# python populate a shelve object/dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, n-gram, shelve

I have a list of 4-grams that I want to populate a dictionary object/shevle object with:

```
['I','go','to','work']
['I','go','there','often']
['it','is','nice','being']
['I','live','in','NY']
['I','go','to','work']
```

So that we have something like:

```
four_grams['I']['go']['to']['work']=1
```

and any newly encountered 4-gram is populated with its four keys, with the value 1, and its value is incremented if it is encountered again.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600790/multiple-levels-of-collection-defaultdict-in-python

Comment: would this work with shelf object?

Comment: and it doesn't work on multiple levels, only two... this is useful of course but completely different thing, appreciate if you remove the duplicate tag

Comment: This can be easily implemented by subclassing the `Shelve` object's `__getitem__` to add a `defaultdict` object on `KeyError`. You can make it work with 4-long tuples either.

Comment: this sounds interesting, but how can I do this?

Comment: isn't this trivial to do? or am i missing the complexity? can't you just populate the dictionary using a 2D loop?

Comment: trivial for you may be complex for others :)

Comment: i wasn't trying to be offensive. I was merely trying to understand the question. You want to populate an n-dimensional array using n-tuples? is that correct?

Comment: basically yes, and want to be able to store it in a persistent form (shelve) as I'm populating it

Comment: and I wouldn't want to use writeback for shelve, so it doesn't seem straightforward as to how to create the keys and increment the values using this type of object

Comment: You can't avoid `writeback` in some form as you'll need to dump whole root-level key into the underlying file since the shelf is only aware of it's immediate keys, and thus you'll need to dump whole keys at once.

Comment: I can use temp variable to store the keys and their values, and this works nicely for single key shelves, but for more keys it is not, that is why I am asking

Comment: @hmghaly : Landed here via "shelve" .Wondering if you could add more on your performance with using both defaultdict & shelve, as per Robert's answer below. I am handling a similar usecase, with HUGE dictionary(that will fail obviously without shelve). Side note-: Statistically asking, why would you want to keep the order of the words ? gibberish, but should we not allow for "I work to go" , or is  the "order" an intentional assumption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import shelve

from collections import defaultdict

db = shelve.open('/tmp/db')

grams = [
    ['I','go','to','work'],
    ['I','go','there','often'],
    ['it','is','nice','being'],
    ['I','live','in','NY'],
    ['I','go','to','work'],
]

for gram in grams:
    path = db.get(gram[0], defaultdict(int))

    def f(path, word):
        if not word in path:
            path[word] = defaultdict(int)
        return path[word]
    reduce(f, gram[1:-1], path)[gram[-1]] += 1

    db[gram[0]] = path

print db

db.close()
```

Comment: looks also good for a solution, but how can I use it to update a shelve object?

Comment: Does it need to be a Shelve? Could you perhaps pickle the dictionary / dump it to json, and then save it to a file yourself?

Comment: yes, as cannot keep opening and closing pickle files everytime I run this code (which I am using it for a very large dataset), or writing and reading from a file, that's why shelve (without writeback) is a very good solution, the point is how to make it work with updating multiple keys (which I think is possible with some use of temp variables but still cannot figure out how to do this exactly)

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. I hope it's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a helper method that inserts the elements into a nested dictionary one at a time, each time checking to see if the desired sub-dictionary already exists or not:

```
dict = {}
def insert(fourgram):
    d = dict    # reference
    for el in fourgram[0:-1]:       # elements 1-3 if fourgram has 4 elements
        if el not in d: d[el] = {}  # create new, empty dict
        d = d[el]                   # move into next level dict

    if fourgram[-1] in d: d[fourgram[-1]] += 1  # increment existing, or...
    else: d[fourgram[-1]] = 1                   # ...create as 1 first time
```

You can populate it with your dataset like:

```
insert(['I','go','to','work'])
insert(['I','go','there','often'])
insert(['it','is','nice','being'])
insert(['I','live','in','NY'])
insert(['I','go','to','work'])
```

after which, you can index into `dict` as desired:

```
print( dict['I']['go']['to']['work'] );     # prints 2
print( dict['I']['go']['there']['often'] ); # prints 1
print( dict['it']['is']['nice']['being'] ); # prints 1
print( dict['I']['live']['in']['NY'] );     # prints 1
```

Comment: Yes, you can just initialize `dict` as `dict = shelve.open('file', writeback=True)` instead, and it will work fine.

Comment: yes, the problem with writeback=True is that we will run into memory problems if the dataset is large (which is the case here), so I want to avoid that